# Выборка из БД по нескольким параметрам

Tags: php, база-данных

Есть выборка товаров из БД по нескольким параметрам: Цвет, тип, форма.
Пытаюсь сделать поиск товаров по одному или нескольким параметрам.
Например: Хочу найти все товары красного цвета и круглой формы или все товары квадратной формы.

Я пробовал делать так:

```
SELECT* FROM БД WHERE Цвет ='Красный' AND Тип = 'Б' AND Форма = 'Квадрат'
```

Однако, при использовании данного запроса, нужные мне товары выводятся только при совпадении всех параметров без исключения, т.е. выбрав, например, "Зеленые" 
 и "Квадратные" я не получу ничего, т.к параметр "Тип" пуст.

Какое условие будет выбирать по параметрам игнорируя невыбранные?

Comment: У вас между всеми параметрами стоит оператор "И", для того, чтобы у вас выбрались красные и круглые объекты объедините эти два условия в круглые скобки, а перед квадратом замените "И" на "ИЛИ"

Comment: *Хочу найти все товары Красного цвета и круглой формы или все товары квадратной формы* - `SELECT* FROM БД WHERE (Цвет ='Красный' AND Тип = 'Б') OR Форма = 'Квадрат'`

Comment: Если параметров мало, то можно сделать несколько методов покрывающие все варианты. Если параметров много, то наиболее простым способом будет выбрать пару основных методов (с параметрами, по которым чаще всего фильтруют), а "тонкую" фильтрацию осуществлять уже средствами PHP

Comment: Вы можете генерировать нужный sql запрос после определения поступивших данных в php. Например если цвет выбран, то добавите условие по выборке цвета в запрос и выполните готовый запрос с нужными условиями.

Comment: @Alex Нравится вариант с генерацией. Могли бы показать кусок примера, незнаю как реализовать.

Comment: @Rust вариант с генерацией настолько плох, что использовать его рекомендуется только если без него вообще никак не обойтись.

Comment: @rjhdby это еще почему? несколько строчек в php лень написать?

Comment: @Alex потому, что генерация запроса катастрофически повышает вероятность устроить в БД трешь, угар и содомию

Comment: @rjhdby  нужно **очень** постараться, чтобы при известных входящих данных  простой генерацией запроса устроить *треш*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой вариант с генерацией запроса.

Для примера у Вас могут поступить `color` (цвет), `type` (тип) и `type_form` (форма) и в бд хранится номер цвета или его `id`. Если у Вас в БД значение цвета хранится как строка (что мало вероятно) используйте `s` вместо `i`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM БД";
$array = array();
if(isset($_POST["color"]))
{
    $array[] = array("color", "i", $_POST["color"]);
}
if(isset($_POST["type"]))
{
    $array[] = array("color", "i", $_POST["type"]);
}
if(isset($_POST["type_form"]))
{
    $array[] = array("color", "i", $_POST["type_form"]);
}

$where = $rows_types = '';
$rows_values = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$arr){
    $rows_types .= $arr[1];
    $rows_values[] = $arr[2];
    if($key > 0){
        $where .= " AND "; //выделили отдельной строкой, здесь вы можете проставить логику OR или AND
    }
    $where .= " `".$arr[0]."` = ?";
}

$sql .= ($where != '') ? " WHERE ". $where : '';

if (!($stmt = $db_conn->prepare($sql))){
    echo "Не удалось подготовить запрос: (" . $db_conn->errno . ") " . $db_conn->error;
}

$params = array_merge(array($rows_types), $rows_values);
$refs = array(); 
foreach($params as $p_key => $p_value){ 
    $refs[$p_key] = &$params[$p_key];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $refs);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$i = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('
        SELECT * 
        FROM table 
        WHERE 1=1
            AND color LIKE :color 
            AND type  LIKE :type 
            AND shape LIKE :shape
        ');

$color = isset($colorFilter) ? $colorFilter : '%';
$type  = isset($typeFilter)  ? $typeFilter  : '%';
$shape = isset($shapeFilter) ? $shapeFilter : '%';

$stmt->bindValue(':color', $color);
$stmt->bindValue(':type', $type);
$stmt->bindValue(':shape', $shape);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста подскажите:  что означает 1=1? $ColorFilter и д.р приходят "из вне"?

Comment: @Rust лайфхак. Если вам понадобится временно отключить одно из условий, по color например, то вы сможете просто поставить перед ним `--`(закоментировать) и не париться с добавлением/убиранием `AND` у следующего аргумента. В принципе оно совершенно не обязательно, просто привычка уже

Comment: @Rust да. Если `$colorFilter` задано, то по этому параметру фильтруем, если не задано, то будут выбраны записи со всеми цветами `%`

Comment: @rjhdby Подскажите, где у вас происходит условие `ИЛИ`, которое было в первоначальном условии, если я ошибаюсь, то буду признателен, за объяснение.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin вопрос был про принципы формирования подобных запросов. Тут показан один из вариантов. Правильную расстановку `OR` и `AND` разумно оставить на усмотрения автора.

Comment: @Alex `LIKE` без `%` выберет точное совпадение фразы

Comment: @rjhdby да, вы правы) не обратил внимание, что поиск будет без 
 %$colorFilter%